# PHP: Obligatory params

Tags: php

What would be the best way, when it comes to practices, to return false if some param is not passed to a PHP function?

Mainly because I am calling this function will be called with params that come from the frotend, which means that the user could pass null as a param, and I want to return false if that happens.

At the top of the function I put:

```
if (empty($param1) || empty($param2) || empty ($param3)) {
            return false;
        }
```

Any better ways of doing this?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Answer (score 5):

In short: Exception. We are in 2011 now, `false` in case of errors is discouraged.

However, I would not test with `empty()`, because this covers `''` (empty string of course) and `0` too. That is probably not wanted in every case.

Comment: Raise a descriptive exception at the very least. If you do pass in bad values, it won't be on purpose and you'll want to know which bit of code went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

We have the SPL [InvalidArgumentException](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php) Exception for that.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:

```
function test() {
  if( count(array_filter(func_get_args(), create_function('$v', 'return isset($v);'))) ) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid parameters");
  }
}
```

Comment: Just thought about similar solution, but with `function($v) { return is_null($v); }` instead (PHP >= 5.3) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Beware : empty(0) will return false.

maybe isset() is better for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the way you are handling it, or you can specify default values for the function.  Many PHP calls handle optional parameters this way.

```
function($param1, $param2='default',$param3='default')
```

This way you can ensure your code has the right values every time or at least "sane" ones regardless of what you are passed.

You can raise an exception in your code as well.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer this way:

```
function a($param1 = null, $param2 = null) {
    if(!isset($param1, $param2)
        return false;
}
```